# How to know instantly if a user presses space in edittext android

Tags: android-edittext, onkeydown, textwatcher

following are the methods i use to get the key event, which are working fine on emulator but doesn't seem to work on device.

following are the methods i use to get the key event, which are working fine on emulator but doesn't seem to work on device.

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        Log.e("onkeydown", "onkeydown");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        Log.e("dispatch", "dispatch");
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        Log.e("onkeyup", "onkeyup");
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int key, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //write code when key press
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```